# How to communicate between 2 programs efficiently?

Tags: vb.net

What is an easy to implement way to communicate between 2 vb.net (3.5) form applications that are running on the same machine?

The current problem is that in each program a user needs to be logged into to use. If the user is logged into one, and clicks a button to launch another, it should pass who is logged in so they do not need to log in again in the second program.

I am looking for a solution that can be used for other purposes as well.

*Note: I am not a VB.NET developer myself, a member of the team I am managing expressed difficulties with this task and I am trying to research a possible solution for him.*

Answer (score 0):

You can do use socket to pass information around. This solution will work for almost any two programs written in any language.

Answer (score 0):

Binary Remoting can also work well for this if everything is .net based.